# Difference in data retrieved by Parse.com and Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

TL;DR: is there a known issue in term of synchronisation of data between Parse.com and Parse Server (half way migration)?

At the moment, our app is still pointing to Parse.com instance, and I see inconsistencies between the what I can see in the Parse.com dashboard, and what I can see in our Parse Server dashboard.

Long story short, I have written a simple Cloud Code function (running in Parse.com) to retrieve `FeedStory` objects linked to a user:

```
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var userPointer = new User();
userPointer.id = "ohVYu44Ow2";

var query = new Parse.Query("FeedStory");
query.equalTo("owner", userPointer);
query
    .find()
    .then(
        function(feedStories) {
            response.success({
                "count": feedStories.length,
                "feedStories": feedStories
            });
        }
    );
```

When calling this function, the result is the following:

```
{
    "result": {
        "count": 0,
        "feedStories": []
    }
}
```

Now, if I run the (almost) exact same code written with node locally, but pointing to our Parse Server instance, that points to the exact same mLab database, I have a different result:

```
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var userPointer = new User();
userPointer.id = "ohVYu44Ow2";

var query = new Parse.Query("FeedStory");
query.equalTo("owner", userPointer);
query
  .find()
  .then(
    function(feedStories) {
      console.log({
        "count": feedStories.length,
        "feedStories": feedStories
      });
    }
  );
```

Result is, as intented in both requests:

```
{ count: 20,
  feedStories: 
   [ ParseObject { _objCount: 1, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'CtW016CDMz' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 4, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'JSVwPPfxlb' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 7, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'C62EX3OWre' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 10, className: 'FeedStory', id: '2Nv5CsRqOx' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 13, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'KhOpPv2lbZ' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 16, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'LYYv2pdg77' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 19, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'qQkyFgPjK0' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 22, className: 'FeedStory', id: '1APpdZGfws' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 25, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'H5tZloAaeI' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 28, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'WCxo6RxBcM' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 31, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'fYbhmdcYUq' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 34, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'k5AHfD5SYq' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 37, className: 'FeedStory', id: '66jipN9ZP0' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 40, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'BHVUx41DyA' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 43, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'wsacsHzQFC' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 46, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'Gkwu1mYQwK' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 49, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'AppKDBJ4UV' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 52, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'IUZALD7Tnl' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 55, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'SCxvA1aG33' },
     ParseObject { _objCount: 58, className: 'FeedStory', id: 'JrilWaN7Cb' } ] }
```

So here is my question: is there a known issue in term of synchronisation between Parse.com and hosted mongodb?

I can see this error happening only with this table, so maybe something is wrong with it, any idea what can cause this?

Hope someone can help,
Cyril

Comment: read up on the syntax in cloud code for "User"  .  its a guess , but your issue may not involve nuances of the migration... rather, it may simply be the use of "User" instead of "_User"   in the cloud code... try it maybe it will work. if that is NG. then maybe look into Async issues with the Promise and   wait for a CB to finish in the query related to the "new User() " call.

Comment: As Robert says, var userPointer = new Parse.User(); The query work  as expected on parse-server. There are only slightly different of response error-code and the format. At least length should equal. The result not match is likely due to the ACL. See the request.user of cloud code. CLP of this class. Another permission issue is due to revocable session, see is your app using legacy session token.